# Debuggin django log on NGINX - DigitalOcean

Tags: django, nginx, logging, droplet

I have a Django application (droplet) on DigitalOcean but I have an issue showing information in a table.

Everything works on my local server but when I deploy to the server on DigitalOcean I don't know where I can see the activity of the server like print outputs. I can see the gunicorn and nginx logs but none of those logs show the Django activity.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**Create your Log directory**

`mkdir logs` in your-app directory

To get your django requests and error log; you'd have to create your indicate the log directory in your nginx server config file.

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/your-app-config`:

```
server {
...
access_log /directory/to/your-app/logs/access.log;
error_log /directory/to/your-app/logs/error.log;
...

}
```

Ensure you have a symbolic link to the sites-enabled folder:

`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your-app /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-app`

**Check that your configuration settings are okay**

`sudo nginx -t`

**Reload Nginx**

`sudo systemctl reload nginx`

Check your log files to read requests & error logs

Comment: sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your-app /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-app.
is 'your-app' the name of the config file or the name of your project folder??

Comment: @Chymdy  your config file :check. Conventionally, your project folder should also be sitting in /var/www/your-project